# Pass arg to testbench during runtime

Tags: chisel

I am rather new to CHISEL.

Is it possible for CHISEL testbench to receive an arg passed in during runtime? 
For example, sbt run --backend c --compile --test --genHarness --dut1

--dut1 is meant to be received by the testbench as an arg. It will be used to determine which DUT to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe that would work.

```
sbt "project myproject" "run my_arg --backend c --targetDir my_target_dir"
```

You can catch that in your own main, strip out your arguments, and pass Chisel its arguments.  Something sort of like this:

````
object top_main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val my_arg = args(0)
    val chiselArgs = ArrayBufferString

```
chiselMain(chiselArgs.toArray, () => iforgettheexactsyntax(my_arg))
```

}
}

Check out ([Chisel runtime error in test harness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748626/chisel-runtime-error-in-test-harness)) for an example main that invokes Chisel.